# Command to install Rasa_nlu using conda

Tags: python-3.x, conda, rasa-nlu

I need to install rasa_nlu for building chatbot in python. Please help with the command to install the same using `conda`

Tried :

```
conda install -c conda-forge rasa_nlu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing Rasa Nlu in a virtual environment. Please try below commands

1. conda create -n myenv python=3.5
2. conda activate myenv
3. pip install rasa_nlu

Answer (score 0):

Please use below -

```
conda install rasa-nlu
conda install tensorflow
conda install sklearn-crfsuite
```